# How to save multiple strings in distinct locations and not in one string

Tags: c#, string

I recently started learning about programming with C# and I have encountered a little problem with my small task that I got.

But first let me just go through a little bit what I learned so far about strings.

So, `string text = Console.ReadLine();`  saves whatever the user writes into that variable.

Next, I worked with a Backpack code where the user can 1. Add items in the backpack and 2. Present the items in the backpack. Here I worked with the `+=` operator so that whenever the user added an item it would be added to the string variable.

Now I am working with a diary/blog  code. The user can:

1. Write a new text (with a title).
2. Search and present the texts written.

I am stuck because I can't just have one string variable for the text that the users writes because it will be overwritten every time the user adds a new text. And I can't use `+=` operator since I don't want to add more text to my string variable. Every time the user adds a new text it has to be saved into a *new* string variable (I guess?).

I just don't know how to write this code.

Comment: You need a collection of strings. Use a [List<string>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) where each new entry gets added to the list.

Comment: The title of your question will be shown in google, so you should provide a meaningful title that helps others with a similar issue to get help

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. If any answer helped you to solve your problem. You can mark it as accepted. This will help future visitors with the same or similar problems to see that this thread is closed and has a definite working answer to the problem. If you don't know how to do it [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) can help

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generic collection like [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). They are build for gathering items of one certain type. In your case it would be: `List<string> allTexts`. You can add strings to it with the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
List<string> allTexts = new List<string>();

string newText = Console.ReadLine();

allTexts.Add(newText);
```

and you can access them via the `[ ]` operator

```
string textNr4 = allTexts[3];
```

Note: indexing starts with `0`!

If you like to search for certain parts of a text you could use LINQ

```
string searchWord = "and";

List<string> allMatchedTextes = allTexts.Where(text=>text.Contains(searchWord)).ToList();
```

this will return all strings that contain the `searchWord`

Comment: What if he added a string check as well? So when a user typed:
"#ShowAllText" he could have an if statement to check the text..

if(text.equals("#ShowAllText", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    foreach(string s in allTexts){ Console.WriteLine(s); }
} else {
    allTexts.Add(text);
}

Comment: @Craig that is true. He could do that. It just wasn't as requirement in the post yet

Comment: Mr hurricane briefly touched on it. It's easier to spot since someone has edited his question :-)

Answer (score 2):

A good way to fix  your issue is to use **Classes**. Maybe you can create a **Blog Class** with two properties **Title** and **Body** and then all you have to do is to simply create a list of Blogs.

```
class Blog
{
     string Title {get;set;}
     string Body {get;set;}
}
```

Each object of **Blog Class** represent a new post and a list of blog will give you the list of all the blog posts.

```
List<Blog> blogs = new List<Blog>();
```